# Which .NET ORM has best support for PostgreSQL database

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, orm

I'm interested to find out which ORM has best support for Postgres SQL database? Does any mapper have, both, LINQ support and ability to generate model from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/)

Comment: This is a linq only answer.

Comment: this project is not maintained anymore. Is there a follow on project?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't compared it against DbLinq but LlbgenPro supports Postgres and is very strong. It supports both Linq and generating the model from the database. In it's just released v3.0 it can generate projects not just for the LlblGen runtime but also for NHibernate, Entity Framework and LinqToSql.

It should be in your list to evaluate.

Comment: Agreed.  We have used both LLBLGenPro and NHibernate to access PostgreSQL databases with much success.

Answer (score 2):

I would say [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info) is your [friend](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasessupportedbynHibernate#PostgreSQL) here.

Comment: How to generate NHibernate model from Postgres database?

Comment: You shouldn't be generating a model from your database anyway. Your object model should reflect the behavior of your system - not the data, which is what a relational database structure is optimized for.

Comment: +1 NHib is be great, and you should think in terms of the making the technology fit your application. Not the other way around. There is a linq provider for NHib; also Fluent NHibernate makes setting up NH easier.

http://fluentnhibernate.org/

Answer (score 2):

Quite an old question, but for anyone happening upon this now (like me), please do check out the [Marten](https://jasperfx.github.io/marten) document & event store for PostgreSQL/.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NEntityDb](https://nentitydb.com). With [NEntityDb for PostgreSQL](https://nentitydb.com/pages/docs/database-providers/postgresql.html) you can query and save data to the database with .NET LINQ Expressions and Fluent API.